# Connection Refused Error when using python requests to get cluster configs using Databricks Clusters API during jobs/workflows

Tags: python, python-requests, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to get the cluster configs using the databricks Clusters API when I run a notebook in a "jobs workflow" on Azure Databricks.

Can anyone advise on the best approach for this please?

The approaches recommended here:

- [Azure Databricks python command to show current cluster config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182503/azure-databricks-python-command-to-show-current-cluster-config)
- [How to call Cluster API and start cluster from within
  Databricks
  Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69013137/how-to-call-cluster-api-and-start-cluster-from-within-databricks-notebook)

...work fine when running notebooks "locally" (outside of jobs/workflows), but does not work during jobs/workflows

The first issue that I noticed when running a notebook in jobs/workflows was that "browserHostName" does not exist in the "tags". Instead there is "hostName" (**EDIT** - do not use "hostName" to resolve this issue, see below):

```
import requests

jsonNotebookConfigs = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson()
dictNotebookConfigs = json.loads(jsonNotebookConfigs)

try:
    strHostName = dictNotebookConfigs['tags']['browserHostName']
except:
    strHostName = dictNotebookConfigs['tags']['hostName']
strHostToken = dictNotebookConfigs['extraContext']['api_token']
strClusterId = dictNotebookConfigs['tags']['clusterId']


strUrl = f'https://{strHostName}/api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id={strClusterId}'
dictHeader = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {strHostToken}'}
response = requests.get(strUrl,
                        headers = dictHeader
                       )
dictResponse = response.json()
```

The second issue is that when running the code above, I get the following error(s):

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

...followed by...

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id=xxx (Caused by 

...followed by...

NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa32582d970>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

...followed by...

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/clusters/get?cluster_id=xxx (Caused by 

...etc...
```

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated, thanks

## Edit 2022-10-17

I have found a resolution (the error derived from the first issue that I identified):

The API requires that `strHostName` should be the workspace instance, i.e.
`strHostName = 'adb-{WorkspaceId}.{RandomNumber}.azuredatabricks.net'`

It turns out that "hostName" does not actually return the workspace instance during jobs/workflows (which causes the second issue).

Instead, you need to use "orgId" which maps to the WorkspaceId, and hard-code the RandomNumber (I do not see any alternative to this). This will fix the issues.

Comment: Is this something that might help ? https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html Seems to have an API to get Cluster Config mentioned. get_cluster_by_name - Not sure if this is the correct option....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however following the linked approach gives a similar error to the original Q:

`
api_client = ApiClient(
  host  = f'https://{strHostName}',
  token = strHostToken
)
clusters_api = ClusterApi(api_client)
clusters_list = clusters_api.list_clusters()
`

...in jobs returns:
`
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/clusters/list (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3a23e3fbe0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))\
`

Comment: Maybe to many requests are going through ? maybe possible to separate the requests with a sleep command ? I think there is some kind of limitations on the number of requests that can be made per minute.